# What is the most appropriate tool to perfrom test automation of Adobe AIR applications?

Tags: automated-testing, test-design, tools, test-strategy

I need to create test automation of the `Adobe AIR` application.

In application under test there are lots of custom controls, `input/output` and `drag and drop` operations.

Now I'm thinking about `Flex Monkey` and a tool, which performs `screenshot-based automation`.

`Flex Monkey` has a lot of restrictions, and `screenshot-based tools` are slow. And what do you think about this?

Comment: Similar to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5340492/automated-testing-for-air-application-html-js-css or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2630243/testcomplete-and-adobe-air

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We were able to successfully automate UI validation with FlexMonkey.

- I agree forums and discussions are quite less (gorilla logic forum is the only forum which has good set of discussion items)
- Application load time, running scripts is little slow but its manageable
- If you have any specific issues you can post in the forum

Please check below links. This was useful for me to get started and good reference material
 - http://www.jamesward.com/2011/03/02/testing-flex-apps-with-flexmonkey-reloaded/

Answer (score 0):

Adobe Air offers great [usability support](http://www.adobe.com/accessibility/products/flex/best_practices.html%20%22usability%20support%22.). Once your app developer supports usability (controls have good names, etc), there are plenty of tools to drive Air using the usability handles. [Plenty of tools listed here](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/testing_usability.html), Selenium is quite popular. If it runs on the desktop, any usability tool should work.